# Is it possible to design custom web UI over HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, bigdata

I am very new to Hadoop tools. So I am asking this doubt. I am using sqoop to push data from my relational DB to HDFS. Now as a next step I want to generate some reports using this data which is stored in HDFS. I have my own custom reports format.
I am aware that using HIVE I can get data from HDFS. but is it possible that I can design my own custom reports(Web UI) over this? is there any other tools I can use?

Else, is it possible to deploy an application( containing HTML GUI and java API's)  on same machine and I can access it via HTTP and can see data present in HDFS?

Comment: you can use Apache Zeppelin (http://zeppelin.apache.org/) to generate reports.I also supports Hive, Spark, Ignite etc

Comment: @Bhavesh I have updated my question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Tableau** for better experience though it is paid but is the best in market,you can even customize your graph or report using tableau.You can get trial version of tableau from their [site](https://www.tableau.com/products/desktop). You can use **PowerBI** from Microsoft which free and works well with Big data. **Ambrose** is created by twitter which is also having good support(I dind't tried this one).

Check [Ambrose](https://github.com/twitter/ambrose) as this is what your are looking for. You can access it via HTTP url.

Comment: I have edited question can you see last lines which I have added. Instead of using any tool for reports can I use my own? In that case how I can read data in HDFS?